# Nuxt can't load stylus file

Tags: nuxt.js, stylus

I am trying to load a stylus file within nuxt.

First I installed the stylus package using `npm i -D stylus stylus-loader`

Then I created a file called `app.styl` in the `assets/style` folder :

```
@require '~vuetify/src/stylus/settings/_colors'
$theme := {
  primary:     $blue.darken-2
  accent:      $blue.accent-2
  secondary:   $grey.lighten-1
  info:        $blue.lighten-1
  warning:     $amber.darken-2
  error:       $red.accent-4
  success:     $green.lighten-2
}

// Import Vuetify styling
@require '~vuetify/src/stylus/main'

.page
  @extend .fade-transition
```

Then I added this to the css array in `nuxt.config.js` :

```
  /*
  ** Global CSS
  */
  css: [{ src: '~assets/style/app.styl', lang: 'styl'}],
```

But then nuxt.js is throwing an error in build :

```
× error friendly-errors » Failed to compile with 1 errors
> log friendly-errors » This dependency was not found:
> log friendly-errors » * ..\assets\style\app.styl in ./.nuxt/App.js
> log friendly-errors » To install it, you can run: npm install --save ..\assets\style\app.styl
```

In my `package.json` I have the version of nuxt to ^2.3.1, stylus to ^0.54.5 and stylus-loader of ^3.0.2.

[Full link to package.json and nuxt.config.js](https://gist.github.com/leo91000/856cef535019381a87f26375482a26a8)

Can you find what is wrong with my setup using these informations ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nuxt asset folder path should be like this for nuxt js version 2

```
 /*
  ** Global CSS
  */
  css: [{ src: '~/assets/style/app.styl', lang: 'styl'}]
```

I hope it will solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

This line worked for me. in nuxt.config.js

css: ['~assets/app.styl']

Comment: hey, can you edit your answer explaining why this works?

Answer (score 0):

A solution from issue discussion [nuxt issue](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/148)
with ref to  [webpack stylus options](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/stylus-loader/#stylusoptions)
and for nuxt latest (2.14.7),

extend webpack configuration mapping all loaders,

```
build: {
    extend (config, { isDev, isClient }) {
      [].concat(...config.module.rules.find(e => e.test.toString().match(/\.styl/)).oneOf.map(e => e.use.filter(e => e.loader == 'stylus-loader'))).forEach(stylus => { 
        Object.assign(stylus.options, {
          //preferPathResolver: 'webpack',
          sourceMap: true,
          stylusOptions: { 
            //use: ['nib'],
            include: ['~assets/styles'],  //include all styl files from folder
            import: [
              '~assets/style/main.styl',  //your main styl file
            ],
          },
        })
        //console.log(stylus)
      }) 
    },
```

this imports the files and include stylus folder as well.